# Nested, AND OR formula

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to get a nested, AND OR formula to stick in Excel - 2 separate sets of conditions within each statement and 3 possible outcomes. I'm at a total loss.

Its an efficacy report that rates the number of errors in less than a 6 month period vs over 6 months. 10 are allotted with 6 the 1st 6 mo period and no more than 4 after that. I've come up with the following.

=IF(AND(OR(B16<10, B17<6, B16<4,B17>6), "EXCEEDS", IF(AND(OR(B16=10,B17=6,

B16=4,B17=6),"MEETS", IF(B16>10,B17>6, B16>4,B17>6),"BELOW"))

Any tips? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you need to get rid of the first two ANDs and add an OR to the last.

Comment: No luck. I need (B16<10, B17<6) to both be true or (B16<4,B17>6) to be true to determine the first outcome. With the change, B16 can go up to 100 and it never reflects the employee to be below goal. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0):

> I need (B16<10, B17<6) to both be true or (B16<4,B17>6) to be true to determine the first outcome.

OK, those revised conditions clarify the use of AND.

```
=IF(OR(and(B16<10, B17<6), and(B16<4, B17>6)), "EXCEEDS", 
 IF(OR(and(B16=10, B17=6), and(B16=4, B17=6)), "MEETS", 
 IF(B16>10, B17>6, B16>4, B17>6), "BELOW", "")))
```

Lining up the conditions helps examine one set to the next. I'm still unclear on what the last is intended to accomplish since if if the first two conditions (`B16>10, B17>6`) are true then the second two (`B16>4, B17>6`) **have** to be true.

Comment: IF(OR(AND(B16>10, B17<6), AND(B16>4, B17>6)), "BELOW"))) is what I was looking for. It works perfectly now. I really appreciate the help. I'm going to keep the nested formulas in separate lines from now on.